# LocalDB Database only shows one record

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, localdb

I have a C# winforms application connected to a localDB in Visual Studio 2012.

When i run the application for the first time i can add a record with the code below.

```
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();

com.Connection = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.BioEngineering);
com.Connection.Open();

com.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Users (Forename, Surname, Company, SecurityLevel, IssueDate, ExpiryDate, CardID) VALUES (@Forename,@Surname,@Company,@SecurityLevel,@IssueDate,@ExpiryDate,@CardID)";
com.CommandText = "INSERT INTO SignInOut (UserID) VALUES (@UserID)";

com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", this.txtMemberId.Text);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Forename", this.txtFirstName.Text);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Surname", this.txtLastName.Text);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Company", this.txtCompany.Text);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SecurityLevel", SecurityLevel);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IssueDate", this.dtpIssueDate.Value);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ExpiryDate", this.dtpExpiryDate.Value);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CardID", this.txtCardId.Text);

com.ExecuteNonQuery();
com.Connection.Close();

MessageBox.Show("New Member has been added!");
this.Hide();
mainMenu.Show();
```

Now, it shows this one record, but when i go to add a second record through the winforms, it says it is updated, but when i go to view the LocalDB it still only has the first record. Ive spent all trying to figure it out, i also have output set to not copy since it cause problems in the bin  DB, which i dont want, i want it to update directly to the localDB? i refreshed as well, any ideas???

Any more information can be provided upon request.

Comment: Can you post the code that calls whatever method this snippet is part of?

Comment: please show the full method and or event that this is happening in.. as well as all relevant code.. can you show where you are doing the binding..?

Comment: Are you missing records from the SignInOut table, or from another table?  It looks like that's the only table that will be inserted to, since you overwrite `com.CommandText`.

Comment: the binding is done through the dataset designer

Comment: As @dsolimano mentioned becides whatever other issue you might be having your code is only writing to the SignInOut table, as you've overwritten the CommandText immediately.  Each command requires a SEPARATE `SqlCommand` object.

Comment: signInOut table only adds the User ID value so that it can initiate it in later time.. Everything works fine on first record, on second nothing is added.

Comment: Aww thanks guys! i got mixed up and thought the signIn one worked but i had that record in by hand. that resolved it!  appreciate it! sorry for the silly mistake